# MsSql Group By twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

[image: examle table]

I have 3 tables:

```
Corridors (CorridorID int Primary)
Locations(LocationID int Primary, LocationMax int, CorridorID int)
Inventory(Inventory ID, SerialNo varchar)
```

I tried a query like this:

```
select C.ID, Count(Distinct(SerialNo)), Sum(L.Max) as TotalCapacity from Corridors as C
Inner Join Locations L on L.CorridorID=C.ID
Inner Join Inventory I on I.LocationID=L.ID
Group By C.ID
```

but Sum gets LocationMax more than one time

True result for me is (30+40+10+20) I mean one time sum for each Locations.
İs it possible doing "Group By" twice? How can I get result like this? (30+40+10+20)

Comment: You could use `MIN
(L.LocationMax) OVER (PARTITION BY LocationID)`

Answer (score 0):

Like @TIM suggested use MAX... try this.
To explain 
Step-1 First partition it by the key columns values you are after... (You can also use Max, min etc based on your requirement.) & find duplicates.

Step 2: Would be put a outer query and sum them up based on the group. Filter any possible duplicates by using where clause

for.e.g

```
 SELECT 
    SUM(LocationMax)AS Kapasite
    ,ID
FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.ID Order by C.ID ) as Row_no,
    C.ID,
    L.LocationMax
    FROM Corridors as C
        INNER JOIN Locations L ON L.CorridorID=C.ID
        INNER JOIN Inventory I ON I.LocationID=L.ID
)T
WHERE T.Row_no=1
Group by ID
```

Comment: Not worked. Gives error: Column   'Locations.LocationID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Error: The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause with ORDER BY.